# Julia macro to code variables dynamically, eg creating a set of dataframes

Tags: julia

Im trying to learn macros so i thought a simple step would be to write a macro that codes a variable based on a dataframe. I could manually set df1 through df*n*, but i dont want to.

For example :

```
macro mac(i)
    quote
        df$i = DataFrame(CSV.File("~/dev/book$i.csv"))
    end
end
```

If i test, in goes 2, but all that comes out is some weird string . .  .

```
@mac(2)

df2 
>> #416#$
```

Comment: Dynamically creating variables with generated names is not a good idea. This is what arrays are for. Make an array of dataframes, and access them as `df[1]`, `df[2]`, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Variables in macros are "randomized" to not conflict with variables in the code where the macro expands in, see the section about [metaprogramming](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/metaprogramming/) and in particular the section about [macro hygiene](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/metaprogramming/#Hygiene). [`@macroexpand`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.@macroexpand) is a very useful tool that lets you see the expanded code and makes it easier to debug.

In this case you need to ["escape"](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.esc) the symbol.

```
julia> macro mac(i)
           quote
               df$i = DataFrame(CSV.File("book$i.csv"))
           end
       end
@mac (macro with 1 method)

julia> macro mac2(i)
           quote
               $(esc(Symbol("df$i"))) = DataFrame(CSV.File("book$i.csv"))
           end
       end
@mac2 (macro with 1 method)

julia> @macroexpand @mac 1
quote
    #= REPL[10]:3 =#
    var"#4#\$"(var"#5#df", var"#6#i") = begin
            #= REPL[10]:3 =#
            Main.DataFrame((Main.CSV).File("book$(var"#6#i").csv"))
        end
end

julia> @macroexpand @mac2 2
quote
    #= REPL[11]:3 =#
    df2 = Main.DataFrame((Main.CSV).File("book$(Main.i).csv"))
end
```

Answer (score 1):

There are much simpler tools to accomplish this than using metaprogamming. The easiest way would be to just define a function that returns the `DataFrame` you want.

```
load_df(i) = DataFrame(CSV.File("~/dev/book$i.csv"))
```

You could then use this basically the same as your macro.

```
julia> df2 = load_df(2)
```

To load all of them at once, you could use a [comprehension](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/arrays/#man-comprehensions).

```
dfs = [DataFrame(CSV.File("~/dev/book$i.csv")) for i in irange]
df2 = dfs[2]
```

Comment: This is absolutely true. The code you suggested would work do the job much more simply, and is more practical. My intention however was just to get more of a sense of how it could work with macros.